# menu items 100% in IE6, help

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

Hi I'm having IE6 issues (surprise surprise).

I can't work out why the menu items are all 100% wide:

http://www.baytobush.com.au/dev

Can anyone shed light on this? must be something is my css...

Comment: STOP SUPPORTING IE6: www.browsesad.com

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions, much appreciated :) From your answers I was able to work out that my version of IE6 (from 'multiple ie's') was not displaying things correctly.

Now I'll need to buy Win XP Pro SP3 just to test in IE6 on my Mac in order to be certain next time :(

Comment: If you are sure that that's the reason, Colin's answer should be accepted as the answer.  However, testing it myself, it does not look right in IE6, unless you chanage the CSS.  Also, I do not recommend using "Multiple IE", as it often has glitches and unexpected behavior.  You'd be better off using virtual machine software, like VMWare or VirtualBox.  Or use a site like http://browsershots.org/ .  I've never used IETester, but I suspect it may have the same problem as "Multiple IE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I view the link using IETester in IE6, the menu looks fine?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it in ie6, just looked at the css.

Make sure you look into the various ie6 "shrink-wrap" bugs when floating elements.
To get around this you have to set widths, or heights, some other hasLayout jiggery.

- http://www.brunildo.org/test/iew_shrink_lay.html
- http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html